# XML not displayed correctly in answers

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, code-formatting, markdown, editor

Recently I've answered a question I did myself and I've not found any way to display an XML code sample.

Check my answer here: [Do stuff before WebDeploy temporary package gets deployed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25023006/do-stuff-before-webdeploy-temporary-package-gets-deployed/25073519#25073519) *(Update: I've temporarily fixed it inserting some text betweehn the bulleted list item and the whole code sample)*.

Where you see "MyTarget", the answer should display an XML sample.

After some investigation, I've found that it won't work if I put an XML sample after a bulleted list.

### Working sample

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <BeforeAddIisSettingAndFileContentsToSourceManifest>GruntUglify</BeforeAddIisSettingAndFileContentsToSourceManifest>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <Target Name="GruntUglify">
    <Exec WorkingDirectory="$(SolutionDir)" Command="grunt uglify" />
  </Target>
```

### Not working sample

- a.
- b.

  GruntUglify

---

If you put something between the bulleted list and the whole XML sample, it works again:

- a
- b

Hey!

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <BeforeAddIisSettingAndFileContentsToSourceManifest>GruntUglify</BeforeAddIisSettingAndFileContentsToSourceManifest>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <Target Name="GruntUglify">
    <Exec WorkingDirectory="$(SolutionDir)" Command="grunt uglify" />
  </Target>
```

Comment: [Code block is not properly formatted when placed immediately after a list item](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3327/code-block-is-not-properly-formatted-when-placed-immediately-after-a-list-item)

Comment: @animuson Oops, I didn't know that there was a Meta.StackExchange...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not a bug. Indenting after a list continues more paragraphs in the same list item:

> - A paragraph.
>
>   Another paragraph in the same item.
> - Another item.

If you want to put a code block in a list item, you must use an additional level of indentation: first, to say you want to remain in the list, and second, to say you want a code block.

> - A paragraph.
>
>   ```
>     // some code
>   ```

If, on the other hand, you do wish to break out of the list, use an unindented empty comment `<!-- -->` between the list and code block.